# Python - File Handling - open() function

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first time here and I hope that it will be a good adventure in here exchanging with you.
It's about file handling. We open a file using the `open()` function, we read its content with the `read()` method. Normally, once we use the `read()` method its displays the full content of the file. Calling two times will be meaningless because reaching the `EOF`, there is nothing to be displayed. Nevertheless, with the piece of code below I do get two times the same output, whereas I should be having it one time.

```
# Opening the file and printing the full content of the file
    # By default, the open() funnction comes in Read mode
    print(open("demofile.txt").read())

    # Going back to the begining of the file
    #open("demofile.txt").seek(0)

    #print("\n")
    # Displaying parts of the file

    # Displaying the first 5 letters
    #print(open("demofile.txt").read(11))

    #print(open("demofile.txt").read())
    print(open("demofile.txt").read())

    # Closing the file
    open("demofile.txt").close()
```

What have I missed here ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way:

```
fh = open("demofile.txt")
print(fh.read())
fh.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I tried this very exact version of the code and it works fine and as intended but then what is the difference ?

Comment: open returns a handle to the file. When you execute read() on the handle, as you expect, the content is read. What you did by `open(...).read()` is, you lost the handle after reading the content. So, you did the following
print(open("demofile.txt").read()) # open the file. read the content. leave out the handle in the open, which is not the nicest way to write code.

By closing the handle, you are cleaning up after opening the file.

In short, you don't have to open the file everytime till you close the previous instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and deep explanation !

Answer (score 0):

This is the right and pythonic way/method to open and read a file:

```
with open("demofile.txt") as demoFp:
    for line in demoFp:
        print(line)
```

Or another approach by reading the whole lines at once (for small files )

```
with open("demofile.txt") as demoFp:
    lines=demoFp.read()
    print(lines)
```